# Is it possible to use an anonymous function as the same name as the field in an object?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function declared like this:

```
const myFunction = (myService: Service) => myService.doThings()
```

Is it possible to create an object that contains this function without having to type it twice?

This is fine but I have to type myFunction twice:

```
const myObject = (myService: Service) => ({
  myFunction: myFunction(myService)
})
```

I would like to do something like:

```
const myObject = (myService: Service) => ({
  myFunction(myService) // Field should be named as'myFunction'
})
```

but this is not allowed.

Comment: You can assign the function to the property with shorthand like `const myObject = (myService: Service) => ({myFunction})` but not the return value of a function call, like in your example.

Comment: If you're only doing this once there's nothing built-in that's more convenient than writing `myFunction` twice.  (And do you really want a field named `myFunction` to not be a function? Seems like the name should be made more illustrative of what you're doing).  If you are doing it more than once then maybe you could [edit] to provide a testable [mre] we can play with.  Right now it's just pseudocode (or missing declarations) so it's hard to proceed.